# jQuery: onclick, edit field and show+save into an variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I have this in Javascript without jQuery:

Here is it: http://jsbin.com/ewihu3

It's working just fine, but I wish to use jQuery for making the code simpler and shorter.

I want exactly same things to do as on the example above, that when you click on the text, it should turn into an input field. And on blur it should display what you've edited in the box, and then make a variable (like e.value on the example above) so I can send that in a ajax call later.

How can i do this in jQuery?

Comment: You haven't even had a look have you? jQuery is the easiest javascript library I've ever come across. Go learn jquery then ask when you get stuck,

Comment: Im stuck at the very beginning making text into a input field

Comment: Well, why don't you have 2 divs? One with just text in and one with a text field? onClick the first one you hide it and show the edit box, then when you onBlur the textbox you show the original div again but change the innerHTML to the value of the textbox. Or, I would do it by just using one text field which is styled with no background and no border and then just change the class to make it look like a text box onFocus.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [jEditable plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)

Or you can start something similar pretty simply by yourself too, with something like this:

```
$('span.editable').click(function() {
   var input = $('<input type="text" />', {
      value: $(this).text()
   }).click(function() {
      $.get('editsave.php?tekstny=' + $(this).value(), function(response) {
         var span = $('span', {
            text: response
         });
         $(this).replaceWith(span);
      });
   });
   $(this).replaceWith(input);
});
```

Comment: Hello. I get error in an unknown function in the jquery library when using this code. And jEditable, afterwards its saving/call it makes, it doesnt show the new value after

Comment: Your server-side script has to "echo" the new value, and jEditable will show this value after saving.
Unknown function error in jQuery? Do you get the name of this unknown function? Maybe you're using an old jQuery release?

Answer (score 1):

#### Editable header or Button by clicking on edit button, type your own text and click on Ok to replace your text.

```js
function editable() {
  var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0];
  var att = document.createAttribute("contenteditable");
  att.value = "true";
  h1.setAttributeNode(att);
}

function noteditable() {
  var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0];
  var att = document.createAttribute("contenteditable");
  att.value = "flase";
  h1.setAttributeNode(att);
}

function editable2() {
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  var att = document.createAttribute("type");
  att.value = "text";
  input.setAttributeNode(att);
}

function noteditable2() {
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  var att = document.createAttribute("type");
  att.value = "button";
  input.setAttributeNode(att);
}
$('.my-button').click(function() {
  $(".my-textbox").focus()
});
$('.my-button2').click(function() {
  $(".button").focus()
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class='my-textbox' contenteditable="false">Hello World</h1>

<button class='my-button' onclick="editable()">Edit</button>
<button onclick="noteditable()">OK</button>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<input type="button" class="button" value="Hello World" />

<br>
<br>

<button class='my-button2' onclick="editable2()">Edit</button>
<button onclick="noteditable2()">OK</button>
```